# AngularJS Performance Issue with $Digest

Tags: angularjs

Scenario:

On `ng_click`, I'm calling a function in its AngularController which is internally calling a function in its AnguarService and this is making a Webservice call and getting a Json object of size 2MB. This response is used to bind data on view using **dir-paginate** as below

```
dir-paginate="item in results | orderObjectBy: predicate : reverse | filter : myFilter  | itemsPerPage: pageSize   track by $index"
```

When the control is trying to exit the function in AngularController, below is the call stack and $digest is taking 14 seconds to finish its execution.

**Call Stack:**

```
(anonymous) (MyAppcontroller.js?v=v1.0.0.0:479)
(anonymous) (angular.min.js?v=v1.0.0.0:131)
$eval (angular.min.js?v=v1.0.0.0:145)
$digest (angular.min.js?v=v1.0.0.0:142)
$apply (angular.min.js?v=v1.0.0.0:146)
l (angular.min.js?v=v1.0.0.0:97)
J (angular.min.js?v=v1.0.0.0:102)
t.onload (angular.min.js?v=v1.0.0.0:103)
```

`$digest` in above stack is taking 14 seconds. I'm unable to fig out how to optimize it.

My code is pretty simple one.

For Example, function in MyController that i'm referring to above is:

```
$scope.getData = function(Id)
{
    MyService.getResponse(Id)
    .then(function(response) 
        {
            $scope.results = response;
        },
        function(message) 
        { 
            $scope.errorMessage = "Error Message";
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for question, did the issue got resolved?

Comment: @RaghuAriga Route cause if my issue was that i had a couple of drop downs for filters and one of these filter drop downs has more than 2000 values. It is loading quick when i bind fewer values to this filter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your code. This problem might be happened because your html binds, some js function called inside a for looping/ng-repeat, or some explicit invoke of the method scope.apply().

Anyway, I had problems like that and I followed this link to solve.

https://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance/

Comment: Yes, I'm using dir-paginate to render the data on View with few filters as shown in the original post(edited). I tried removing the filters and it is still the same.

Comment: Maybe you can try: 1) Simplify your json object with only necessary data for your screen; 2) Paginate the data on server side and get only the data for the selected page.

Comment: Yah, this definitely increases performance but it takes lot of time and resources. I'm wondering why $Digest is taking 14 seconds to finish its process.

Comment: are you using chrome Timelime tool? This is a good tool to measure and check this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 2MB json text response, you probably are doing something wrong. But, supposing you are doing well...

Posible solutions:

- Split the json in multiple request if it's possible.
- Use a WebWorker to process the json while angular is rendering, in that way, you avoid blocking view rendering process.

Comment: Splitting is not possible in my scenario. So i'm using pagination.

Comment: Well... pagination is to split your json anyway, right? You have to do multiple requests (pages) to get all the previous json.